# observe(FIRDataEventType.value) is not firing when child is added to node

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My event listener is not firing when I add a new entry to the node, even though it is supposed to.
If I update an entry in the node manually, in Firebase console, the listener fires correctly.

```
func getMeetMedia(_ callBack: @escaping ([MeetMedia]) -> ()) {

    let media48HourQuery = meetMediaUserRef
        .queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
        .queryStarting(atValue: startTime)
        .queryEnding(atValue: endTime)
    media48HourQuery.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in

        var fetchedMeetMedia = [MeetMedia]()

        let snapDic = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        if snapDic != nil {

            var counter = 0
            for child in snapDic! {

                let childDic = child.value as? NSDictionary

                let title  = childDic?["title"] as? String
                let mediaID = childDic?["mediaID"] as? String
                let timestamp = childDic?["timestamp"] as? Double
                let fromUserID = childDic?["fromUserID"] as? String
                let toUserID = childDic?["toUserID"] as? String
                let mediaType = childDic?["mediaType"] as? String
                let unread = childDic?["unread"] as? Bool

                let newMeetMedia = MeetMedia(fromUserID: fromUserID!, mediaID: mediaID!, mediaType: mediaType!, timestamp: timestamp!, title: title!, toUserID: toUserID!, unread: unread!)

                fetchedMeetMedia.append(newMeetMedia)
                if unread == true {
                    counter += 1
                }

            }

            callBack(fetchedMeetMedia)
            unreadMeetMediaCount = counter
        }
    })
}
```

To add new entries, this is what I'm using:

```
        let newVideoPostChild = meetMediaUserRef.child(mediaID)

        newVideoPostChild.setValue(newVideoPost)
```

for background context, I am implementing a global listener for unread: true for various nodes.
Newly added entries have an unread: true   set for them, therefore the unread count needs to be incremented, but the listener is not firing.

I did get this working by using a timer and querying the firebase DB every few seconds but I shouldn't need to do that because the listeners should be persistent..

Also, I first fire up the listener in HomeVC.
When I add a new entry in my app to that node, I am not on HomeVC, I am on another VC. However, i never detach the listener.

Comment: Ok I think I found the issue. When I create the query I am using the current time. But later when I add a node, the timestamp is later than the start time, so the query thinks that the new entry doesn't fit into the time range.

Comment: i created a new function that uses observeSingleEventOfType  (.value) and I call this repeatedly with a Timer

Comment: Queries are immutable, meaning that you (unfortunately) cannot change the timestamp after you've created the query. So creating a new one seems the only way to go. I'd limit the number of times that you do that though. If you're creating a new query every few seconds, you're essentially polling the database. It'd be better to more efficient create a single query that also gets events in the (near) future and then filter them client-side.

Comment: Frank, I suppose I could call a timer , client side, that updates the variables: startTime and endTime   every 10 minutes or so, and updates the query. Is that what you had in mind?